# HTML required validation message style issue in Bootstrap from field

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my Bootstrap form field with the calendar icon and it's required. However when the error massage is showing it's going to be mess like below image. 
[image]

HTML code is

```
<div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
     <input type="text" value="" class="form-control error" name="from" id="from" required">
 </div>
```

Bootstrap CSS below

```
 .input-group-addon, .input-group-btn, .input-group .form-control {
        display: table-cell;
    }
.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn {
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%;
}
.input-group-addon {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
.input-group .form-control {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML5 required error

```
<label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>
```

So HTML code is like below when error occur

```
<div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
     <input type="text" value="" class="form-control error" name="from" id="from" required">
<label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>
 </div>
```

So How to fix this and set calendar Icon with in lining the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the elements inside `input-group` are `display: table-cell`, you have to provide `display: table-row` to the `label` for it to appear in new line (in a different row as in a table).

**EDIT**

In case, you want the error to appear exactly below the input and start right after the calendar icon, I would suggest you to use `position: absolute` instead.

Check edited code snippet:

```css
.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn,
.input-group .form-control {
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1%;
}

.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-group .form-control {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* #from-error {
  display: table-row;
} */

#from-error {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -32px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control error" name="from" id="from" required>
  <label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the issue is not fixing for this. it only set for the calendar icon row. :(

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The error message not come to under the input field. it comes only below the calendar icon. (Run the snippet and you can see)

Answer (score 0):

**try this may work**

```
 <div class="input-group">
 <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
 <input type="text" value="" class="form-control error" name="from" id="from" required">
 </div>
  <label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>
```

Comment: `<label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>` 
This line is set from the when HTML 5 validation happening, so I can't change the place?

Comment: ok then use <br> between <input> and <label id="from-error" class="error" for="from">This field is required.</label>